# Where do random script tags come from?

Tags: javascript

I found this in my web application.

```
<script async="" src="http://www.shopathome.com/Injection/Inject.aspx?cid=74179042&amp;guid=0c179887-0d15-4009-860f-3f2c3d602885&amp;ver=6.0.9.2&amp;domain=www.google.com" type="text/javascript" id="sahinjectionScript"></script>
```

I have know idea how it got there.

Is this some sort of injection attack.  How can I get rid of it?

**Research and Reference**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting

Comment: If you are using PHP, call `htmlspecialchars` on any dynamic/untrusted content you are echoing as html. E.g. `<div class="post-title"><?php echo htmlspecialchars($post_title); ?></div>`

Comment: Where did you find it? In one of your file or in the source code of your browser?

Comment: Could be injected by a toolbar.

Comment: You mean content that is entered in to the browser by the user?

Comment: It's not in any file, I can see it in the DOM, that is where I copied it from.

Comment: I did a refresh and it disappeared.

Comment: @livingston_mechanical then its probably your browser. clean your computer from spyware and adware, remove unwanted toolbars and browser extensions.

Comment: It was an 'extension' in chrome...have know idea how it got there...the extension did not have a presensce as a toolbar.

Comment: What was the name of the extension ? Are you on Windows ?

Comment: There are a lot of "free" software packages that sneak browser extensions in to their installers. The authors of the free software get paid affiliate fees by the extension writers. A [prime example](http://www.zdnet.com/a-close-look-at-how-oracle-installs-deceptive-software-with-java-updates-7000010038/) is Oracle who, hatefully, force you to deselect the "I want the crappy Ask Toolbar installed" checkbox every time they release a security update for the Java runtime on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information [at should i remove it](http://www.shouldiremoveit.com/ShopAtHome-com-Toolbar-18424-program.aspx) - clean up the add-ons you have installed on your workstation.

If the worrying code had appeared in the page that came from the server (and was not, as appears to be the case here, injected by a browser extension you have installed):

1. Take your server off-line
2. Change your passwords and virus scan your workstation to make sure that wasn't the attack vector
3. Bring up a clean server
4. Reinstall your application from an untainted source
5. Monitor the new live version to see if the attack reoccurs
6. Analyse the server you have taken off-line to find out how the attack worked
7. Fix any security problems and deploy to a new clean server